# Cosine of a Linear System

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $m\times n$ matrix, $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are vectors of dimension $n\times 1$. All of them have real entries. I am interested in solving the system of equations $$\mathbf{y} = \cos(\mathbf{Ax}+\mathbf{b})$$where cosine is applied element wise on the vector $\mathbf{Ax}+\mathbf{b}$. If cosine is not there, the solution is straightforward and I know this. The problem is that $\arccos(\mathbf{y})$ is one-to-many mapping. Thus for each $\mathbf{y}$ among that, we need to consider whether a solution exists or not. How can I solve this problem?

I tried the following and got stuck after a while. Let $\mathbf{z} = \arccos(\mathbf{y})$. Since $\cos(2d\pi+x)=\cos(x)$ for any integer $d$, it follows that  $$z_i = 2d_i\pi + r_i$$ for every positive integer $d_i$ and $r_i\in(0,2\pi)$. Thus, the system of equations (after rearrangement in vector form) becomes $$2\pi\mathbf{d}+\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{Ax}$$ Thus, we are now interested in solving a system of equations to find the integer vector $\mathbf{d}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ such that above equation is satisfied. Is this correct? Or intuitively, is there a vector in the column space of $\mathbf{A}$ such that it can be expressed as the LHS above for some integer vector $\mathbf{d}$? Are all this steps correct?

Comment: $+1$ , where does this show up in practice  ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi This is from a machine learning problem I am working on. The above is a constraint in an optimization problem in $\mathbf{y}$ which is a convex problem except for this constraint (and $\mathbf{x}$ appears only in this constraint).

Comment: yes but what is the practical application (ex. radar, medical imaging, etc..) of this problem ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi This comes up as a intermediate step in solving a black box optimization problem. The end application is online learning.